# Bernoulli trial assembly line problem

Tags: statistics

A manufacturing company changes an acceptance scheme on items from a production line before they are shipped. An inspector takes 1 item at random from a box of 21​items, inspects​ it, and then replaces it in the​ box; a second inspector does likewise.​ Finally, a third inspector goes through the same procedure. If any of the three inspectors find a​ defective, the entire box is sent back for​ 100% screening. If no defectives are​ found, the box is shipped.

What is the probability that a box containing 3 defectives will be​ shipped?

At first I thought it would be done the following way:
$$(\dfrac{{{3}\choose{1}}{{18}\choose{0}}}{{{21}\choose{1}}})^3$$

But I realized that the answer was extremely small, after thinking about it I realized that this represents the probability of pulling out the defective item 3 times after placing it back into the box.

So I came to the conclusion that what actually needed to be done was.
$${\dfrac{{{3}\choose{1}}{{18}\choose{0}}}{{{21}\choose{1}}}}+\dfrac{{{3}\choose{1}}{{18}\choose{0}}}{{{21}\choose{1}}}+\dfrac{{{3}\choose{1}}{{18}\choose{0}}}{{{21}\choose{1}}}$$

This resulted in me getting ~0.4287 which appears to be incorrect as well. Does anyone know how I'm supposed to go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we know that there are 3 defective items out of 21 in the box.
The probability that an inspector will pick a defective item is always $\frac{3}{21}=\frac{1}{7}$.

So the probability you are looking for is $P(\text{no defective is found in all 3 checks})$ because if any defective is ever found then it will be checked and surely will not be shipped.

$$P(\text{no defective is found in all 3 checks})=\left(\frac{18}{21}\right)^3=\frac{216}{343}\approx0.630$$

So the main issue here is probably a careless mistake because you ended up finding $P(\text{a is found in all 3 checks})$ in your first attempt instead.